# selenium-webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Не хочет запускаться селением на стандартном порту. Когда меняю порт то все нормально при первом запуске, но после остановки этот порт становится занят java. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
sh-3.2# webdriver-manager start

[10:53:03] I/start - java
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.36
-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.20.0
-jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar
-port 4444

[10:53:03] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 14841.  
10:53:04.228 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'.
10:53:04.231 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444 2018-03-16
10:53:04.378:INFO::main: Logging initialized @432ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:53:04.514 ERROR [SeleniumServer.boot] - Port 4444 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port option

[10:53:04] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 0

sh-3.2# lsof -i :4444

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE  NAME

java    12841 root    5u  IPv6 0xae97bc8db155355      0t0  TCP *:krb524(LISTEN)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуй обойтись без этой странной утилиты webdriver-manager.